# Dynamically changing ListView elements

Tags: android

I'm using a Listview to display three columns of information from a Cursor in two TextViews on the screen. The left TextView is static while the right one has translations in two languages that toggle when selected.

My problem is that this works fine until I scroll the ListView, at which point the adapter and the ListView seem to become unsynchronized, leading to flaky behavior and finally a null pointer exception.

Here's the onListItemClick code:

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    //first revert previous selection to English
    if(previous_position!=99){
      View vo =l.getChildAt(previous_position);
      TextView pt = (TextView)vo.findViewById(R.id.english);
      pt.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
      pt.setText(previous_text);
    }

    //now show current selection in Hindi
    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.translation);
    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    t.setText(gloCursor.getString(3));

    //finally remember where we changed things so we can revert them
    previous_position = position;
    previous_text = gloCursor.getString(3);

    // adapter data notification
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I've commented out notifyDataStateChanged as it hasn't worked for me in this case.

Would appreciate any insight or maybe a better design for this.

thanks,
P.

Comment: It would help if you made your code un-minified

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your `getChildAt` code with:

```
View vo = l.getChildAt(previous_position - l.getFirstVisiblePosition());
```

Comment: No luck with this either. Still getting an error and false highlights when I scroll past the first screen. The mapping between the ListView shows on the screen and the model in the adapter makes it difficult to do what I want.

Comment: if you have an error, post it. the other, probably more reliable, way would be to make these changes inside your adapter.

Comment: Thanks for the help mango. I'm using the adapter to get the view but then going directly to the cursor to get the value I want to swap in. Instead, I can bring in all three columns in the adapter and just pull in the column I want. Will try that and see where I get.

Comment: The paradigm I was thinking of is the radio button. It seems natural to locate the selected list item and do something to it while reverting the previous selection to its original state.

Comment: i agree. it certainly does seem like the most natural. but using `getChildAt` with a listview can be extremely cumbersome because you only have access to what's visible and the index will change to reflect that. unfortunately, you have no other choice if you're trying in the way that you are. in my experience, it has been much more beneficial to simply do the work in the adapter.